# Comparing the distribution of several compositions given as percentages

Tags: distributions

I need to show that the proportion of different cell types in blood from two individuals are the same.

Example: There are 6 cell types and

```
  Person 1 has the proportions: 0.07, 0.05, 0.4, 0.3, 0.15, 0.03   (Sums to 1)
  Person 2 has the proportions: 0.07, 0.05, 0.3, 0.2, 0.35, 0.03   (Sums to 1)
```

Can anyone please suggest a test to show that the proportions in the two individuals are (or are not) significantly different?

Answer (score 1):

If the proportions are based on counts, then something like a chi-square test of the counts is an appropriate test.

If the data arrive as proportions, then my impression is that this is essentially an ill-posed problem without much more information. One pessimistic view is that you are comparing relative frequency distributions with no idea of sample sizes and that can't be done in significance test terms. A more optimistic view is that you have to recast the problem somehow as a modelling problem, although I don't have ideas on how to do it here.

This is a problem of growing importance for at least one reason, although I know essentially nothing about blood and a bit more about soil or sediment where loosely similar questions arise. In the past data like this were often based on someone counting objects on a microscope slide, or some similar manual method. Now data like this are often just spat out of a machine. You put your materials into the machine and you get measurements out. In some cases the software provides some kind of uncertainty measure, for example, but often not.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm wondering how anyone else who came up with such a problem dealt with it. All I can really do right now is manually inspect it, but it would be nice to have some p value to show the significance.

Comment: Absent a model for measurement or sampling error, where would that come from?